# ValueError : embedded null character while Importing a JSON file using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to import a JSON file in python but I keep running into an error

```
with open('e:\0_1export.json', 'r') as f:
data = f.read().strip();
```

Error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-abd9cb3a729a> in <module>()
----> 1 with open('e:\0_1export.json', 'r') as f:
  2     data = f.read().strip();

ValueError: embedded null character
```

Here is the pastebin of the contents of the file i am trying to import .

https://pastebin.com/mCZiPktJ

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

`'e:\0_1export.json'` must be written as `'e:\\0_1export.json'` or `r'e:\0_1export.json'`. Otherwise, Python treats '\0' as a NULL character (the character with the code 0).

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I feel like such a child!